# How do I use Haskell's FFI on structs?

Tags: haskell, word-wrap, ffi

I have created the following C library for reading an image:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int width;

    unsigned char* red; //length=height*width
    unsigned char* green;
    unsigned char* blue;
} Contents;

Contents readJPEGFile(const char* inFilename);
```

I can't really find any info using arrays and structs with the Foreign Function Interface.
How would I proceed to be able to use my library in Haskell?

I tried to use the following example as a base: http://therning.org/magnus/archives/315 but then the hsc file was compiled down to a hs file that only contained the above c-code and nothing more (and of course it can't be compiled).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds as if you have a build issue; I do seem to recall that I used the very page you reference as an example when I was writing an FFI interface into the Windows Win32 DDEML library. For example, one of the structures we use is

```
typedef struct tagHSZPAIR {
    HSZ     hszSvc;
    HSZ     hszTopic;
} HSZPAIR, *PHSZPAIR;
```

`#include "ddeml.h"` brings this in to the `DDEML.hsc` file. We access it with:

```
data HSZPair = HSZPair HSZ HSZ
instance Storable HSZPair where
    sizeOf _                     = (#size HSZPAIR)
    alignment                    = sizeOf
    peek ptr                     = do svc   <- (#peek HSZPAIR, hszSvc)   ptr
                                      topic <- (#peek HSZPAIR, hszTopic) ptr
                                      return $ HSZPair svc topic
    poke ptr (HSZPair svc topic) = do (#poke HSZPAIR, hszSvc)   ptr svc
                                      (#poke HSZPAIR, hszTopic) ptr topic
```

Unfortunately, I can't show you what this compiles to at the moment because I don't have a Windows box handy, but the generated code was just as above, except with `#size HSZPAIR` replaced with `(64)` or whatever and so on.

(If you really want to see what was generated, or need help doing your build, e-mail me and I'll help you out.)

Answer (score 10):

The basic FFI support includes only scalar types.  Everything else you wind up doing with address arithmetic.  The [section on foreign types](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/ffi/ffi/ffise5.html#x8-240005.1) in the FFI documentation gives the basics, and you can find an example in the [FFI Cookbook](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFICookBook).

At one time you could use tools like [Green Card](http://www.haskell.org/greencard/) and [H/Direct](http://haskell.org/hdirect/) to generate marshalling and unmarshalling code for you.  For reasons I don't understand, these tools have not been updated in a long time.  As far as I can tell the current tool of choice is [`hsc2hs`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html).

---

Edit: As noted in comment (thanks ephemient), [`c2hs`](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/c2hs/) is also popular, and since `c2hs` is from Manuel Chakravarty it is likely to be good.

Comment: I've used c2hs (http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/haskell/c2hs/) in the past, which is (a) still maintained and (b) easier than hsc2hs, in my opinion.

Comment: c2hs is a nice tool, but is not able to manage enums or unions

Comment: There's also `c2hsc`, for producing hsc files mostly automatically from C header files.

Answer (score -3):

[Hackage has several packages which use FFI](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html) which you could look at for examples.

Comment: If you could mention just a few it could be great.